# Siddhi logical AND with within, executes callback unexpectedly

Tags: wso2, complex-event-processing, siddhi

Using Siddhi CEP 3.1.2 as standalone library, I am using try figure out how to correctly trigger the callback handler under a number of conditions.

1. Two events joined by logical AND

   `a AND b`

I find with the above that if i provide both events, then i can trigger the callback handler, however I've also seen that if i subsequently provide either a or b then the handler is also triggered.  I did not expect the latter to happen as I assumed there would be no match due to the previous execution of the handler... Is there a way to clear the streams following a successful match?

2. Two events joined by logical AND including a within.

   `a AND b within 5 sec`

I've also found in the second case, that the "within" option is seemingly ignored. The callback is triggered regardless of the time gap between the events a and b.

Have I misunderstood the Siddhi documentation? I'd appreciate any guidance on these. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

These are two bugs based on our testing and fixed with the [PR #436](https://github.com/wso2/siddhi/pull/436).

The following test cases are added to ensure the correct behavior:

1. [Test `A and B`](https://github.com/wso2/siddhi/blob/9737e71cf277852212f47a3e98f36455dd2c97c9/modules/siddhi-core/src/test/java/org/wso2/siddhi/core/query/pattern/LogicalPatternTestCase.java#L702)
2. [Test `every (A and B)`](https://github.com/wso2/siddhi/blob/9737e71cf277852212f47a3e98f36455dd2c97c9/modules/siddhi-core/src/test/java/org/wso2/siddhi/core/query/pattern/LogicalPatternTestCase.java#L810)
3. [Test `A -> B and C within 1 sec`](https://github.com/wso2/siddhi/blob/9737e71cf277852212f47a3e98f36455dd2c97c9/modules/siddhi-core/src/test/java/org/wso2/siddhi/core/query/pattern/LogicalPatternTestCase.java#L985)

You will get these fixes from the next release onwards or else you can build Siddhi from source and test them right now. Here is a blog post on how to build and use Siddhi from source: [Siddhi 4.0.0 Early Access](http://www.javahelps.com/2017/01/siddhi-400-early-access.html).